# Loop for executing all tests in a directory makefile on windows

Tags: loops, makefile, command

I have the follow fragment of makefile which actually doesn't work:

```
tests: serial.o parallel.o
    for %i in (..\tests\*) do @echo %i
```

The error when I launch `make tests`  is: "i non expected." and I'm working on windows.

I tried to run the command from both vscode (powershell) and normal prompt. What am I missing?

Comment: Conventionally, `make` implementations default to using a POSIX shell for executing recipes.  The recipe in you example code appears to assume a different shell language, maybe Powershell.